# If $\sum |a_k|$ is convergent, is limit of $a_k=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Why? 
I was trying to prove that sum(a_k) converges absolutely then sum{(a_k)^2} converges. And the solution assumed this.

Comment: If $\sum a_k$ converges, then $a_k\rightarrow 0$. This is so because $a_k=S_k-S_{k-1}$ where $S_k$ is the $k^{\rm th}$ partial sum of the series ($(S_k)$ is Cauchy).

Comment: The title isn't supposed to be the first line of your question. How would you like it if the title of movies was the first line in the movie?

Comment: As for the thing you're trying to prove, if you look around the site you'll find it. **Hint:** I've proven it here.

Answer (score 9):

If **any** series converges, absolutely or not, the general term sequence's limit is zero, since:

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\implies a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}S-S=0$$